# The functions of the word "before"

Tags: grammar, functions

Are the functions mentioned below correct?

1-conjunction 2-preposition 3-preposition 4-adverb 5-preposition

> 1- Always look both ways before you cross the road.
>
> 2- You should always wash your hands
> before meals.
>
> 3- Before leaving he said goodbye to each of them.
>
> 4- He said he had never seen her before.
>
> 5- The bus stop is just before the school.

Comment: They correct according to old-fashioned grammar analyses.

Answer (score 2):

In modern grammar "before" is a preposition in all your examples. Consider:

Items like "before", "after", "since" uncontroversially occur as prepositions when they have an NP as complement, and there's no basis for assigning them to different categories according as they take an NP or a clause -- or no complement at all. Traditional grammar has:

*before the meeting*.....................preposition + noun

*before we arrived*.......................subordinating conjunction + sub clause

*(I hadn't seen her) before*....... adverb, no complement

This is just a matter of varying complementation, which is commonplace. Compare verbs:

*I know her father*.......................verb + NP

*I know that he's ill*.....................verb + clause

*I know*............................................verb without complement

Or noun:

*a belief in God*.............................noun + PP

*the belief that God exists*........noun + clause

*her beliefs*....................................noun without complement

Moreover, in all three constructions, "before" takes the same modifiers, e.g. "a short while".

For the record, Jespersen argued for treating "before" the same in all three constructions nearly a hundred years ago.

Comment: Interesting, but this does not mean traditional grammar is useless. We need educate both of them

Comment: Regardless of what modern grammar holds, ESL students learn that a preposition has an NP complement because that's the most practical way for them to learn to use English correctly. The phrase "*you cross the road*" is not an NP, so "before" isn't a preposition in (1). Or if it is, this requires English learners to be able to determine when a clause is actually an NP, which is beyond those without a background in Linguistics.

Comment: @gotube If's far easier for students now, because words like *out* and *before* are always prepositions, which is what students always thought in the first place. They also behave like prepositions and not adverbs, which is a huge relief. And when students say or write stuff like *I hate here* or *Here is cold* it's easy to correct them (PPs can't freely appear as subjects or objects). Tonnes of other areas too. For example *because + clause* and *because + of-phrase* are now the same word. Etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct for 1, 2, 4 and 5.

In 3, you can argue it's a preposition because it's followed by a gerund, which is often considered a noun. But it's also arguable that "leaving" is a reduced clause meaning "*he left*", which would make "before" a conjunction.

Comment: Unusually, -1. Gerunds are verbs. If we have to say *verbs functioning as nouns*, we should be clear that that means the verb is being a subject or object (of a verb or preposition). It hasn't turned into a noun, and it has no noun-like qualities. It's easy to show it's a verb in (3) because we can use an NP object and not an *of*-PP after the verb *Before leaving the shop*, but not _*Before leaving of the shop_. Also it can take adverb modifiers and not adjective  ones, etc, etc.