# “Before starting work, I look at my to-do list…” Is ‘’before‘’ a prep. or conj? If it is a conj. what was omitted?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> Before starting work, I look at my to-do list and prioritize it.

Is ‘’Before‘’ a  preposition or conjunction?

If it is a conjunction, what has been omitted?

---update
Thank you very much, guys, for your help!

I think @James K and @IMSop make a good point, let's end here and no need to dig deeper. It makes sense to learn more practical usages.

Comment: It's a Preposition.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/338838/the-functions-of-the-word-before and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133189/what-part-of-speech-is-before-in-the-phrase-before-we-meet-again  Be aware that not all textbooks and not all ESL teachers give the same answer.   I wonder how much it would affect your understanding of the phrase if I told you that nobody knows, and it is a deep mystery of English grammar?

Comment: James K makes a really important point: grammar is *an on-going attempt to analyse and understand language*, and not something that has any independent "truth" or "value". In terms of *understanding* English, choosing labels for hard-to-categorise words and parts of speech may not be as useful as just learning how they are used.

Comment: @IMSoP But that's just it. A good analysis or description can help you understand how a word is used!!! A rubbish one can't.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Oh, definitely, and maybe there's a useful way of describing this example, I don't know. But I do know that there are some words in English that just defy categorisation. It's like families of verb endings in French or Spanish - they're useful to a point, but eventually you have to just call some verbs "irregular", and learn them by heart.

Comment: Why do you think something has been omitted?

Comment: @StuartF feels like :  Before I am starting work, or something else, but...I am not sure. That's why I asked.

Comment: @IMSop, love what you said